# Using sonar from windows server 2008

Tags: administration, sonarqube, windows-server

I want to install sonar on Windows Server 2008 r2 64.
I configured my `conf/sonar.properties` file like this:

```
sonar.web.host : [my_server_ip]
sonar.web.port: 8888
sonar.web.context: /sonar
```

I started `StartSonar.bat`, in windows firewall prompt I answered to grant access from public networks.
When I tried to access http://[my_server_ip]:8888/sonar from server it's all good. But when I tried to access to this page from another one computer I can't.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some kind of networking issue.  From the "public network" computer, can you `telnet [your_server_ip] 8888` and get a connection?  If not, then you need to diagnose why.  Get your local network guru involved.

Without knowing more about how your network is configured, if your Sonar server is on an internal network (whereas your "public network" computer might or might not be), etc...